Syntax to place bounds on a set of generic functions in an implementation
I have the following code
struct MyStruct { val: i32 }

impl MyStruct {
    fn foo(&self) { println!("foo"); }

    fn bar<F>(&self, f: F) -> i32
    where F: Fn(&i32) -> i32, {
        f(&self.val)
    }

    fn baz<F>(&self, f: F) -> i32
    where F: Fn(&i32) -> i32, {
        f(2 * &self.val ) 
    }
}

This works perfectly, and achieves the following desired behavior:
fn main() {
    let item = MyStruct { val: 3 };

    item.foo(); // "foo"
    print!("{}", item.bar(|x| x + 1)); // 4
    print!("{}", item.baz(|x| x + 1)); // 7
    print!("{}", item.baz(|x| (x, x))); // mismatched types
}

As you can see, some of the implemented methods share a common bound that must be repeated each time. I'd like to eliminate that repetition, ideally with syntax rather than a macro.
Ideally I would want to replace the impl MyStruct {} block with the following:
impl MyStruct {
    fn foo(&self) { println!("foo"); }
}
impl<F> MyStruct
where F: Fn(&i32) -> i32, {
    fn bar(&self, f: F) -> i32 { f(&self.val)     }
    fn baz(&self, f: F) -> i32 { f(2 * &self.val) }
}

This doesn't work though, saying that The type parameter "F" is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates. I don't really understand why it would need to be constrained in this case. I also don't want to solve this with a trait like: MyTrait<F: Fn(&i32) -> i32>because the overhead of writing accessor functions is no better. My actual use case has a criteria set of more than the one bound, and more than two functions that should be implemented conditionally on whether that criteria set is met.

You'd need to make MyStruct generic over F for this to work. But I doubt that's what you want. Then any one instance of MyStruct could only take one kind of Fn type as an argument to any of its methods. The repeated bounds are necessary here to declare your intent. The point of generics is not reducing verbosity.

As you said that would eliminate the functionality I am aiming for, as I want bar and baz to take any closure meeting the criteria. Conceptually what is wrong with the syntax I used that leads it to give that error? Is there any ambiguity that is being avoided, or is this reasonable syntax sugar that's consistent with Rust's principles that just hasn't been implemented yet?

Conceptually, type parameters cannot be unconstrained because the compiler couldn't infer which impl to call based on the type of the caller. I don't think your syntax is reasonable as it already exists in the language and means something different. You can reduce the size of your trait bounds in most cases with a super trait + blanket impl: Playground
